# Using a mobile phone image sensor with a raspberry pi

Tags: camera

There is the Raspberry-Pi HQ camera with a very limited number of lenses. I know that there are mounting adapters, but with the 5.5x full frame equivalent of the sensor, finding a wide angle lens is a mission and expensive.

So I was wondering, for example, if I could use the Sony IMX650 from a Huawei P30 and mount it on the Raspberry-Pi camera interface? The HQ camera sensor is a Sony IMX477.

Any Raspberry Pi version/model would be fine to use for me.

Answer (score 1):

It all boils down to the two devices sharing the same interface to achieve this. If there is an adaptor for your camera to the CSI port of the pi, then it should be pretty straightforward. Alternately, you can see if there it can be connected via the USB. . After you create this physical connection, then you'll have to determine the appropriate software - which is another matter.

Good luck! It would be a very cool feature to have.